# Summing sequences in r using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to sum pieces of a series using data.table in r. The idea is that I define a start index and an end index as columns in the table, then make a third column for "sum of the series between start and end indexes."

```
series = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
a = data.table(start=c(1,2,3),end=c(4,5,6))
a[,S := sum(series[start:end])]
a
```

Expected result:

```
   start end  S
1:     1   4 10
2:     2   5 14
3:     3   6 18
```

Actual result:

```
Warning messages:
1: In start:end : numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
2: In start:end : numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
> a
   start end  S
1:     1   4 10
2:     2   5 10
3:     3   6 10
```

What am I missing here? If I just do a[,S := start+end] the code executes as one would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would work if you make this a rowwise operation so each `start` and `end` represent a single value at a time.

```
library(data.table)
a[,S := sum(series[start:end]), 1:nrow(a)]
a

#   start end  S
#1:     1   4 10
#2:     2   5 14
#3:     3   6 18
```

Answer (score 3):

An option is to loop over the 'start', 'end' columns with `Map`, get the sequence (`:`) of the corresponding elements, get the `sum` and `unlist`, the `list` column to assign (`:=`) it to a new column

```
a[, S := unlist(Map(function(x, y) sum(x:y), start, end))]
```

-output

```
a
#   start end  S
#1:     1   4 10
#2:     2   5 14
#3:     3   6 18
```

---

The `:` is not vectorized for its operands i.e. it takes just a single operand on either side, and that is the reason it showed a warning

Answer (score 3):

You can use the arithmetic series formula:

```
a[, S := (end - start + 1) * (start + end) / 2]
```

Gives:

```
   start end  S
1:     1   4 10
2:     2   5 14
3:     3   6 18
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try `cumsum` like below, which allows you apply vectorized operations within `data.table`

```
cs <- cumsum(series)
a[,S := cs[end]-c(0,cs)[start]]
```

which gives

```
   start end  S
1:     1   4 10
2:     2   5 14
3:     3   6 18
```